# How to import a variable value from txt file in ant?

Tags: ant, cmd

I am relatively new to Ant, I have written an ant build file that will open command prompt in windows 7 and pass an argument line. 
So how would I pass a variable in this argument line whose value it will get from a txt file in a certain folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `loadfile` task.

See [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455309/how-to-read-data-line-by-line-from-a-file-using-ant-script) for examples