# Apache ant : Read value from file and assign it to value of an attribute

Tags: java, apache, ant

I want to set the value of a replace filter with the contents saved in text file, please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data line by line from a file using ant script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455309/how-to-read-data-line-by-line-from-a-file-using-ant-script)

Comment: Its not duplicate . I need to replace a token value with file content rather than simple reading a file.

Comment: provide what you have done so we can assist (ant sample)

Answer (score 0):

The ant [property task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) can be used to read a properties file

For example

```
<property file="foo.properties"/>
```