# How to read just a first line of an file.txt with ANT?

Tags: ant, task

I would just read the first line of an file.txt with ANT without using externals libs.

my file is file.txt and his content :

```
3432424
43545435
756767
345354345
```

Comment: You should be able to get there from the information contained here.  Its not an exact match but close enough.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455309/how-to-read-data-line-by-line-from-a-file-using-ant-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [*loadfile*](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) ant task to load the file and [*HeadFilter*](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#headfilter) in *filterchain* to filter out only the first line of loaded text.

If your text file e.g. *test.txt* contains the following

```
abc
def
ghi
```

then the the target given bellow will print only the first line ***abc*** on the console

```
<target name="read">
    <loadfile property="temp" srcfile="./test.txt">
        <filterchain>
            <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.HeadFilter">
                <param name="lines" value="1" />
            </filterreader>
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <echo>${temp}</echo>
</target>
```

Comment: yes yes! It's exactlly what I want ... <filterreader>. Thank you