# Merge multiple text files line by line using ANT

Tags: ant, merge, concatenation, ant-contrib

How do I merge multiple text files into one file. I want to read text line by line from each file and then merged text into the final output file.  Sample text in my files are:

**File 1 :**

```
  aaa  
  bbb  
  ccc
```

**File 2 :**

```
  ddd  
  eee  
  fff
```

**File 3 :**

```
  ggg  
  hhh  
  iii
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  aaa  -->from file 1
  ddd  -->from file 2
  ggg  -->from file 3
  bbb  
  eee  
  hhh  
  ccc  
  fff  
  iii
```

I have tried the target below

```
<target name="mergeappvars" >  
    <concat destfile="${out.dir}/ApplicationGV.txt" force="no">  
        <fileset dir="${work.dir}/application"  
     includes="*.txt"/>  
    </concat>  
</target>
```

My logic is appending one file after another and I got the output as

aaa
  bbb
  ccc
  ddd
  eee
  fff
  ggg
  hhh
  iii

Comment: I have tried the target below
 
 <target name="mergeappvars" >
  <concat destfile="${out.dir}/ApplicationGV.txt" force="no">
   <fileset dir="${work.dir}/application"
         includes="*.txt"/>
  </concat>
 </target 
 
I get the output as shown below  

  aaa  
  bbb  
  ccc  
  ddd  
  eee  
  fff  
  ggg  
  hhh  
  iii

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own logic. This link will help you how to load a file and read from file using ant. 
[How to read data line by line from a file using ant script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455309/how-to-read-data-line-by-line-from-a-file-using-ant-script)